# Hooks placements in Drupal

Tags: 7, hooks

I am trying to place some hooks, but I don't even think they are being called.

THEMENAME_menu_alter(&$items)

and

THEMENAME_user_view_access($account)

are the hooks I am placing in my template.php file. However, they don't seem to be reacting to it. And yes, I am converting the dummy THEMENAME placeholder to the name of my theme in use.

But my real question is: are these hooks just for use in Custom Modules? Or can they be called in from template.php too?

If its just for custom modules then I guess that would explain why it's not reacting. But even so how is one suppose to know if a certain hook is only for a module or not?

P.S: I have also tried clearing the cache several times.

Comment: hook_menu and such hooks has to be in a custom module. For all theme functions and preprocess functions, you definitely can implement them in a theme, but most hooks won't work in a template.

Comment: Looks at the function names - `module_implements`,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Default you can consider all hooks can be extendible using custom modules...

Hook Documentation says

> Hooks are how **modules** can interact with the core code of Drupal. They
>   make it possible for a module to define new urls and pages within the
>   site (hook_menu), to add content to pages (hook_block, hook_footer,
>   etc.), to set up custom database tables (hook_schema), and more.

In template.php you can override functions which are exposed by hook_theme or functions like theme_*

There exists a good [documentation](https://drupal.org/node/1728096) that explains which functions you can override using template.php..